# What to do for ordered messages in a message queue with multiple consumers

Tags: message-queue

I have a queue between 2 services, and I send objects of two models in this queue, `A` & `B`. Each `B` can have a foreign key to an `A`. Objects of model `B` are already saved in DB of consumer service, but objects of `A` will be created in sender service, and then they are sent to consumers to be saved in their DB.
Now, when the sender creates an `A` and sets foreign key of one of `B`s to it, it will send a `create` message of type `A` to this queue, followed by an `update` message of type `B` to indicate that the `B` object should be updated. When we have only one consumer, and messages are guaranteed to be received in order, we have no problem; The `A` object will be created and saved to consumers DB, and the `B` object will be updated. But when we have multiple instances of the same consumer, there will be a problem: The `A` message will be handed to one instance of consumer, and the `B` message will be handed to another instance. They're trying to work simultaneously, and before `A` object is saved to DB, the second instance will try to set a foreign key to it, and DB prevents it.

I think one solution is to send all information of `A`s in each `B` message, so when an instance is trying to update a `B`, it can create `A` by itself. The problem is that it doubles the time that is needed to serialize a `B` object.
Another solution is to withhold sending `B` messages before receiving acknowledges of `A` messages. But this slows down our system, and forces it to save it's state.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Create separate queues for each consumer and populate all queues with all events. If this is not doable, then you should redesign your events to make them independent (which means something like your first idea - include detailis of A into B). You just can't process dependent events by independent consumers.

Comment: If I create separate queues for each consumer, what is the point of having several consumers? I have them to parallelize consuming messages and speed it up.

Comment: I forgot to ask, why you need multiple customers anyway :) Well, I can understand speed concerns, but for parallel processing you need some kind of synchronization between dependent events and such syncronization causes delays. As a compromise, you can create separate queues for A events for all customers and single queue for B events; customers are then required to process A queues first and B queue afterwards. Assuming that B events occur more frequently, you will have almost no performance penalty. Such schema does work even when some customers go temporary offline.